# Hide WVD url using Azure services. FrontDoor? AppGW?

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, wvd

we are doing POC for one client of Windows Virtual Desktop service(2020 spring version)
and client requested to hide url that is being used by default: https://rdweb.wvd.microsoft.com/arm/webclient/index.html, there is no customization of this in WVD service., client want to see like: https://customdomainmain.com/arm/webclient/index.html

So trying to do this with FrontDoor or AppGW (ready to hear other solutions as well)
In both cases I get: 'Message: AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application:' searching info for this: suggests to register app in AAD, not sure how but what I tried nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit of Azure Functions, which allows you to execute your code in a serverless compute platform and setting your own Custom URL using the corporate domain name. the same idea as myapps.3tallah.com or mail.3tallah.com, for sure it would be up to you to set your preferred subdomain name.

Please refer to this blogpost [Configure Custom URL redirection for Windows Virtual Desktop – WVD](https://3tallah.com/configure-custom-url-redirection-for-windows-virtual-desktop-wvd/)